# How do you remove the first character of a string?

Tags: string, go

What is the suggested method to remove the first character of a string?

I've looked through the documentation for string methods but I don't see anything that works like javascript's [String.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Comment: There is no "the best" solution for every problem. `str[1:]` would do the trick.

Comment: take a look here https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-go

Comment: @zerkms Would do the trick if your string is ASCII, `"µñ"[1:]` doesn't quite work as desired.

Comment: @muistooshort indeed. And with zjw compound glyphs it becomes even harder (near to impossible?) to do at all.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming that the question uses "character" to refer to what Go calls a [rune](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), then use [utf8.DecodeRuneInString](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString) to get the size of the first rune and then slice:

```
func trimFirstRune(s string) string {
    _, i := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s)
    return s[i:]
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/ExDEcVaoJvo)

As peterSO demonstrates in the playground example linked from his comment, range on a string can also be used to find where the first rune ends:

```
func trimFirstRune(s string) string {
    for i := range s {
        if i > 0 {
            // The value i is the index in s of the second 
            // rune.  Slice to remove the first rune.
            return s[i:]
        }
    }
    // There are 0 or 1 runes in the string. 
    return ""
}
```

Comment: While `trimFirstRune` is correct, it appears to be less efficient than `trimLeftChar` and `trimLeftChars`: https://play.golang.org/p/ZOZyRORkK82. See the source code for `utf8.DecodeRuneInString`.

Comment: Good question. Rather than number of runes, if the characters to trim are known [strings](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) TrimLeft() worked best for me.

Comment: Downvoting because this requires you to read the entire CSV into memory as a string ... It's much much more efficient to pipe readers one to another and do filtering inline. Imagine you're retrieving a 1GB CSV across the network and you have to wait for the entire 1GB to be in ram before starting to process?

Comment: @MikeGraf  The question asks how to trim the first character from a `string` and that's what I answered.  To trim the first character from a large CSV file retrieved across the network, read [UTFMax](https://godoc.org/unicode/utf8#UTFMax) bytes, trim the first character using the code above, and create a [multireader](https://godoc.org/io#MultiReader) with the remaining bytes and the original io.Reader.

Answer (score 19):

This works for me:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    input := "abcd"
    fmt.Println(input[1:])    
}
```

Output is:

```
bcd
```

Code on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/iTv7RpML3LO

Comment: But it doesn't work in general, consider what happens when `input := "µabcd"`.

Comment: @muistooshort good point, I did not test unicode characters like `µ`. I'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: This answers the question being asked and, in my case, all of my characters are ASCII (controlled by me, not the user).  Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 17):

In Go, character `string`s are UTF-8 encoded Unicode code points. UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding.

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> For statements with range clause
>
> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code
>   points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive
>   iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of
>   successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second
>   value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code
>   point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the
>   second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and
>   the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trimLeftChar(s string) string {
    for i := range s {
        if i > 0 {
            return s[i:]
        }
    }
    return s[:0]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", "Hello, 世界")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChar(""))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChar("H"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChar("世"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChar("Hello"))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChar("世界"))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/t93M8keTQP_I

Output:

```
"Hello, 世界"
""
""
""
"ello"
"界"
```

---

Or, for a more general function,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func trimLeftChars(s string, n int) string {
    m := 0
    for i := range s {
        if m >= n {
            return s[i:]
        }
        m++
    }
    return s[:0]
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("", 1))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("H", 1))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("世", 1))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello", 1))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("世界", 1))
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", "Hello, 世界")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello, 世界", 0))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello, 世界", 1))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello, 世界", 7))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello, 世界", 8))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello, 世界", 9))
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", trimLeftChars("Hello, 世界", 10))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ECAHl2FqdhR

Output:

```
""
""
""
"ello"
"界"

"Hello, 世界"
"Hello, 世界"
"ello, 世界"
"世界"
"界"
""
""
```

---

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Unicode UTF-8 FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#UTF8)

[The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/)

Comment: (disclaimer: I'm not nitpicking (and I've +1d you), I understand it's a complicated problem, not sure it's possible to solve it with less than few dozens/hundreds of kilobytes of code) Given the OP did not explain what they mean by `character` it they actually meant "a glyph" then something like `‍⚕️` would be really hard to handle right.

Comment: @zerkms: ‍⚕️ Man Health Worker: https://play.golang.org/p/qgloqE1a4az

Comment: That's what I meant: it's a single glyph, so `trimLeftChars(s, 1)` should entirely remove it. (if you're on linux - try mobile phone with a recent OS or other OS (windows/mac) to see that if properly rendered - those 4 codepoints are joined into a single glyph)

Comment: @zerkms: I was careful to use the word character (code point), not glyph. I only promised `trimLeftChars`, not `trimLeftGlyphs`.

Comment: A code point need not be a character. Think of combining characters, RLM or the dead ugly/stupid BOM.

Comment: @Volker: This is all explained in the Unicode Standard: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/UnicodeStandard-10.0.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Another option is the `utf8string` package:

```
package main
import "golang.org/x/exp/utf8string"

func main() {
   s := utf8string.NewString("")
   t := s.Slice(1, s.RuneCount())
   println(t == "")
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/utf8string

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the string into an array of runes, pop the first rune and then convert the array back into a string. Here's the one-liner:

```
str = string([]rune(str)[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the best oneLiner solution I had come across for this useCase using **strings** package

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    myString1 := "/abc/def"
    myString2 := "Hello World"
    myString3 := "HHello World"

    fmt.Println(strings.TrimPrefix(myString1, "/"))
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimPrefix(myString2, "/"))
    fmt.Println(strings.TrimPrefix(myString3, "H"))
}
```

Output for the above:

```
abc/def
Hello World
Hello World
```

Go Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/tt3GgDjHXFg?v=goprev

Comment: Good stuff, simple and exactly what I wanted.